# Find the position of a word and get 3 words before and after the word in R

Tags: sql, r

I am new to this `library(stringr)`. In my `df` I have this column named Sentences which contains a single sentence in each row. Now I want to find the position of a word and 3 words before and after the word..

For eg-

```
string <- "We have a three step process to validate 
           claims data we use in our analysis."
```

If we search for the word `validate` it will return 8 ,and the words---- `'step' 'process' 'to' 'claims' 'data' 'we'`.  I tried `str_match` and `str_extract`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `strsplit` and `grep`:

```
myString <- "We have a three step process to validate claims data we use in our analysis."

# Split the string into individual words
splitString <- strsplit(myString, " ")[[1]]

# Find the location of the word of interest
loc <- grep("validate", splitString)

# Subset as you normally would
splitString[(loc-3):(loc+3)]
# [1] "step"     "process"  "to"       "validate" "claims"   "data"     "we"
```

---

#### Update

If you have multiple strings in a vector, you can try something like the following. I've modified it a bit to be on the safer side and not try to extract non-existent positions.

```
words <- c("How data is Validated?", 
           "We have a three step process to validate claims data we use in our analysis.",
           "Sample Validate: Since No One vendor can provide the total population of claims in a given geographic region")

x <- strsplit(words, " ")
lapply(x, function(y) {
  len <- length(y)
  locs <- grep("validate", y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  min <- ifelse((locs - 3) <= 0, 1, locs-3)
  max <- ifelse((locs + 3) >= length(y), length(y), locs + 3)
  y[min:max]
})
# [[1]]
# [1] "How"        "data"       "is"         "Validated?"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "step"     "process"  "to"       "validate" "claims"   "data"     "we"      
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "Sample"    "Validate:" "Since"     "No"        "One"
```

The result, as you can see, is a `list` of vectors.

Comment: > words
[1] "How data is Validated?"                                                                                         
[2] "We have a three step process to validate claims data we use in our analysis."                                   
[3] "Sample Validate: Since No One vendor can provide the total population of claims in a given geographic region," 

> splitString <- strsplit(words, " ")
> loc <- grep("validate", splitString)
> loc
[1] 2

It would be helpful if the position of validate in every sentence is  returned and the +-3 words.
Thank you for your help